# Defn. of weighted projective space in Harris: Algebraic Geometry

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, projective-space

The most basic intuition of weighted projective space is the following:

We define $\mathbb{P}^n_{a_0, \dots, a_n}$ where $a_i  \in \mathbb{Z}$ to be the space $\mathbb{C}^{n+1} - \{0\}$ with the relation that $[Z_0: \dots : Z_n] \sim [\lambda^{a_0}Z_0: \dots : \lambda^{a_n} Z_n ]$

I wanted to find a more rigorous definition, like the one given in Harris. However, some of the jargon he uses is slightly unfamiliar to me. He writes that,

Let $a_0, \dots, a_n$ be any positive integers, then we define weighted projective space to be the action of the group $\mathbb{Z}/a_0 \times \cdots \mathbb{Z}/a_n$ on $\mathbb{P}^n$ generated by the automorphisms 
$$[Z_0: \dots : Z_n] \to [Z_0: \dots : \zeta \cdot Z_i : \dots :Z_n] $$
where $\zeta$ is the $a_i$-th primitive root of unity.

I haven't come across the phrase "group action generated by automorphisms". What is meant by this?

Comment: It means that each of the maps you define, this is, multiplication by $\zeta$ in the $i$th component, are in fact automorphisms of $\mathbb{P}^n$. In other words, there is a group homomorphism from  $\mathbb{Z}/a_0\mathbb{Z}\times\cdots\times\mathbb{Z}/a_n\mathbb{Z}$ to $\operatorname{Aut}\mathbb{P}^n$.

Comment: Oh sure. That makes a lot of sense. I wish there was a "math jargon" tag.

Comment: I'd suggest Dolgachev's paper http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~idolga/weighted82.pdf

for a more detailed exposition.